# NavigationBar PushViewController not working

Tags: iphone

I have been stuck at this problem for awhile now. I have a UIVIEW(SelectionScreen) that has been pushed in by using

```
SelectionScreen *aSelectionScreenViewController =[[SelectionScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectionScreen" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController pushViewController:aSelectionScreenViewController animated:YES]

[aSelectionScreenViewController release];
```

That works fine. But now the problem comes with this class. This class actually holds another Class called SelectionScreenTable. So the Architecture would be like this
SelectionScreen
-SelectionScreenTable

So now in the didSelectRow method of the SelectionScreenTable.m file 
i tried pushing another Class(class is called Graph.h) but its not working, the code i use is exactly the same as the above.

So i tried pushing Graph at the very beginning of the mainFlow of the app, just to see if my code is working or wrong, and yes, its working.

So i was wondering , how can i solve this? Detecting the superclass and then push the view into the superview? IM A OBJ-C newb though, codes and examples would be nice. Any Idea guys? thanks for reading btw

Comment: Does the problem lies with my SelectionScreen? 
The SelectionScreen holds the SelectionScreenTable by adding it as a subview. This is how i made my SelectionScreen "hold" the SelectionScreenTable

Comment: SelectionScreen.m

SelectionScreenTable *aSelectionScreenTableViewController = [[SelectionScreenTable alloc] initWithNibName@"selectionScreenTable" bundle:nil];

aSelectionScreenTableViewController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,896,613);
aSelectionScreenTableViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(576,380);

[self.view addSubview: aSelectionScreenTableViewController.view];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by using a transition animation instead . .

```
GraphView *viewController =[[GraphView alloc]initWithNibName:@"GraphView" bundle:nil];
    viewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.14 *(0)/180.0);
    viewController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,1025,769);
    viewController.view.center = CGPointMake(512.5, 374.5);

    UIView *theCurrentView = self.view;
    UIView *theWindow = [theCurrentView superview];
    [theCurrentView removeFromSuperview];
    [theWindow addSubview:viewController.view];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.35];
    [animation setType: kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
    [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToGraphView"];
    [viewController release];
```